# PayPal Orders API schema

Tags: php, laravel, api, paypal, guzzle

I am setting up a payment integration with PayPal Checkout Buttons and Paypal Orders API V2. Payments are going throw, but now I want to include items in my Order request, but I getting:
[image]

As PayPal docs say I have to pass `array (contains the item object)` [Link to Orders API purchase_unit object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit) [Link to Orders API item object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-item). But I'm still getting this error.
This is my request:

```
public function createOrder($value, $order, $products, $currency = 'EUR')
    {
      return $this->makeRequest(
        'POST',
        '/v2/checkout/orders',
        [],
        [
          'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
          'payer' => [
            'name' => [
              'given_name' => $order->billing_firstname,
              'surname' => $order->billing_lastname
            ],
            'email_address' => $order->email_address,
            'address' => [
              'address_line_1' => $order->billing_street_address,
              'admin_area_2' => $order->billing_city,
              'postal_code' => $order->billing_postcode,
              'country_code' => $order->billing_country_code
            ],
          ],
          'purchase_units' => [
            0 => [
              'amount' => [
                'currency_code' => $currency,
                'value' => $value,
              ],
              'description' => 'Order: ' . $order->order_serial_number,

              'items' => [
                0 => [
                  'name' => 'Item1',
                  'unit_amount' => 100,
                  'quantity' => 1
                ],
              ],
            ],
          ],
          'application_context' => [
              'brand_name' => config('app.name'),
              'shipping_preference' => 'NO_SHIPPING',
              'user_action' => 'PAY_NOW',
              'return_url' => route('approval.paypal', $order->id_order),
              'cancel_url' => route('payment.cancelled', $order->id_order),
          ]
        ],
        [],
        $isJsonRequest = true
      );
    }
```

I'm using: Laravel and Guzzle/HTTP to perform payment requests.

As I say, payments are going throw, but when I try to add Items to Order, I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted the full (rest of the) error response that details the problem, so there may be another issue we can't see, but one thing that's missing is the `amount.breakdown.item_total` subtotal, which is required when passing an `items` array with amounts: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-amount_breakdown

A simple example in the API's JSON format, which you can adapt to PHP array syntax:

```
// based on example array from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/
  "purchase_units": [{
      "amount": {
        "value": "17.49",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "breakdown": {
          "item_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "17.49"
          },
        }
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "17.49"
          },
          "quantity": "1",
          "name": "item 1",
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
```